# Square shaped plot combined with subplot, shared x axis

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to have two subplots, where the first subplot is squared and the x- and y-axis share the same limits. Additional to this, the second plot should shares the same x-axis but a independent y-axis.

The final result should look like this:

[image: Wanted solution with squared plot and additional second plot]

How do I derive a plot in this form?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to require a fixed `figsize` and additional to this use a `GridSpec`, that works within the given `figsize` to make sure, that the space is used in the way we want it.

The following part generates a squared plot and a smaller subplot with the fixed `height_ratio` of 3:1. The reason for the `figsize` is that we want to have a square (which determines the `width` of the figure to be `3` and a height of `4` (`=3+1` as given in the height ratio).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[3, 1])
```

[image: Solution with hspace-gap]

To close the gap between the subplots, we know give the additional parameter `hspace=0`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[3, 1], hspace=0)
```

[image: Solution without hspace-gap]

A complete working example could look like this:

```
import pylab as plt    
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[3, 1],hspace=0)

# generate some random test data
datatemp = np.random.random_sample((100,2))
datatemp2 = np.random.random_sample((100,2))*np.array([1,2])

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax0.scatter(*datatemp.T)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1],sharex=ax0)
ax1.scatter(*datatemp2.T)

ax0.grid(True)
ax1.grid(True)

ax0.set_xlim(0,1)
ax0.set_ylim(0,1)

ax1.set_ylim(0,2)

# cosmetics 
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0,2,0.5))

plt.setp(ax0.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```